# How can I get my cat used to smaller portions?

Tags: cats, diet

My cat has started to become a bit old(9 years old) and as a result he is less willing to play and prefers to lounge around or cuddle. The problem here is that he wants to eat the same amount as he usually eats which is causing him to get fatter. I wanted to lower his portions but he just starts meowing until I give him more food and I am worried that I will stress him out if I refuse to give him food when he begs for it. So my question is that how can I get my cat to get used to smaller food portions.

Comment: Are you feeding wet or dry? Or a mix? Did you lower the portions all at once, or gradually?

Comment: Sometimes, as with humans on a diet, you just have to put up with complaints. Cats are very good at training humans, but we do have the option of resisting that training.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As cats grow older, it is not necessarily just the caloric intake they need that is changing, but also the relative composition of nutrients.

Interestingly, and contrary to what one might think intuitively, the caloric intake requirement might even increase with age as the body has more and more difficulty with fully processing certain components in the food.

There are specific foods for senior cats and geriatric cats that try to factor in the typical changes in food composition requirement.

While the definition of what makes a cat senior or geriatric may vary somewhat depending on whom you ask, I've mostly heard that senior would be around the age of 10, some sources put this at an earlier age, and some at a later age.

Keep in mind that just like with humans, not every cat is the same when it comes to aging, so it is always a good idea to consult with your vet and identify the individual needs of your cat, formulate a plan to monitor for potential changes in these needs, and the appropriate nutritian (and potentially medication as well).